# Internet Explorer 7 transparency fix

Tags: 7, theming

I have a menu that has a transparent background with the following CSS:

```
background-color: transparent;
background-color: rgba(113,157,174,0.7); 
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99dddddd,endColorstr=#99dddddd);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99dddddd,endColorstr=#99dddddd)";
```

In IE, it doesn't have any color; it is just white. I used an Internet Explorer fix, in which I used the following code:

```
filter: alpha(Opacity=45);
background-color: #0010A5;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99dddddd,endColorstr=#99dddddd);
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr=#99dddddd,endColorstr=#99dddddd)";
```

The only thing this did was to make it purple, but it wasn't transparent at all.

```
![screenshot][1]
```

I know it is possible because I've seen it done before. What am I doing wrong? How do I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer, it was in fact `filter: alpha(Opacity=45);` inside the IE fix, but apparently it needed to be in the `-inner` of the class, instead of the regular class.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the [PNG Fix module](http://drupal.org/project/pngfix)? Maybe it can solve the problem.

Comment: I'm working off of drupal 7, that only has versions for 5 and 6.

Comment: You can try http://drupal.org/project/pngbehave then.

Comment: It's not an image file though. it's just a menu with a background-color. will it still work?